# Expedia EAN / TravelNow search using city name issue

Tags: php, xml, api, rest

I have implemented the EAN hotel search API using XML and PHP. And I have the following issue when searching and listing hotels.

Search details

```
City - Soho
Country - GB
Arrival - Aug 1, 2013
Departure - Aug 2, 2013
Rooms - 1 room with 2 adults
```

Results in TravelNow site

```
http://www.travelnow.com/templates/331656/hotels/list?lang=en&currency=GBP&secureUrlFromDataBridge=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.travelnow.com&requestVersion=V2&destination=&standardCheckin=8%2F1%2F2013&standardCheckout=8%2F2%2F2013&checkin=8%2F1%2F13& amp;checkout=8%2F2%2F13&rating=0&targetId=AREA-d5cfc783-9e42-4440-9200-0bd17397c37f%7Clandmarks&roomsCount=1&rooms[0].adultsCount=2&rooms[0].childrenCount=0&filter.sortedBy=our_rec&filter.hotelName=&filter.lowPrice=0&filter.travelerOpinion=0&filter.breakfastIncluded=false&subscriptionInfo.termsConditionAgreement=false&subscriptionInfo.wantNews=false&subscriptionInfo.wantNewsletters=false&tab=list
```

In TravelNow site, we searched for Soho, London, United Kingdom as shown in the above URL

Request sent

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?currencyCode=GBP&minorRev=99&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&locale=en_US&cid=XXXXXXXX&sort=OVERALL_VALUE&xml=<HotelListRequest><city>Soho<%2Fcity><countryCode>GB<%2FcountryCode><arrivalDate>08%2F01%2F2013<%2FarrivalDat e><departureDate>08%2F02%2F2013<%2FdepartureDate><numberOfResults>25<%2FnumberOfResults><supplierType>E%7CV<%2FsupplierType><supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED<%2FsupplierCacheTolerance><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>2<%2FnumberOfAdults><%2FRoom><%2FRoomGroup><%2FHotelListRequest>
```

Response received

```
<ns2:HotelListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/">
<EanWsError>
<itineraryId>-1</itineraryId>
<handling>UNKNOWN</handling>
<category>EXCEPTION</category>
<exceptionConditionId>-1</exceptionConditionId>
<presentationMessage>No Results Available</presentationMessage>
<verboseMessage>Result was null</verboseMessage>
<ServerInfo serverTime="05:45:17.821-0500" timestamp="1375181117" instance="54"/>
</EanWsError>
<customerSessionId>0ABAAA36-B023-AF91-4022-F2DA5EE95A74</customerSessionId>
</ns2:HotelListResponse>
```

I also searched with city string "Soho, London, United Kingdom" given for city/destinationString didn't list any hotel. We used API tester http://devhub.ean.com/apitester/index.html too and received the same results.

This search mostly says no results for many cities in London. We tried "destinationString" based search shown in http://developer.ean.com/docs/read/hotel_list/examples/XML_Alternatives but didn't work either. How do we need to pass the destination/city? Even when it shows hotels they are not in/around the given city.

Let us know how to implement the above request to work properly to list the hotels in a given city. This works only for a few cities we have listed in the search. Shown below is a list of exact city names in London we use to pass in the request, inside the  block. If below city names are incorrect, then how do they need to be corrected?

Bayswater-Paddington,
Belgravia,
Bloomsbury-Soho,
Canary Wharf-Docklands,
Camden Town,
Chelsea,
Chelsea-Knightsbridge,
City of Westminster,
Chinatown,
East End,
Fulham,
Greenwich,
Holborn,
Hammersmith,
Hampstead,
Hampstead-Camden Town,
Hounslow,
Islington,
Knightsbridge,
Kensington,
Lambeth,
London,
London area,
Mayfair,
Mayfair-Marylebone,
Marylebone,
Pimlico,
St. Pancras - Islington,
Soho,
Southwark-Waterloo

Please help with a REST/XML request string that works for the above city/cities.

I haven't accepted any of the current answers but are looking for more correct answers that rings a bell.

Comment: It is because you send the destination string "soho" but in Ean Api Name of city is  "SoHo". That's why the error is shown to resolve that you may try my code given below.

Answer (score 1):

I am using REST method for get hotel list

My code is given below

```
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=14
&cid=55505
&apiKey=p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym
&customerUserAgent=&customerIpAddress=
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&city=Lasvegas
&stateProvinceCode=NV
&countryCode=US
&supplierCacheTolerance=MED
&arrivalDate=08/25/2013
&departureDate=08/27/2013
&room1=2
&numberOfResults=25
&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED';

  $header[] = "Accept: application/json";
  $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  $rt =  curl_getinfo($ch);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($response);
  echo "</pre>";
```

You want more details.
See this [links](http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotel_list/examples/REST_Basic_Availability)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use geoSearch tab given at api tester by ean:

```
http://devhub.ean.com/apitester/index.html
```

after that you have to insert destination string in that and fetch the city name according to the responce.
Here is the sample code how you have to do this:

```
$destination="soho";//YOUR Destination string

$Geosearch='https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/geoSearch?cid=50555&minorRev=99&apiKey=**XXXXX(your_api_key)**&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CLocationInfoRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clocale%3Een_US%3C%2Flocale%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdestinationString%3E';
$Geosearch.=$destination;
$Geosearch.='%3C%2FdestinationString%3E%0A%3C%2FLocationInfoRequest%3E';

$locate = json_decode(file_get_contents($Geosearch),true);
$citynames=$locate['LocationInfoResponse']['LocationInfos']['LocationInfo'];
$citysearched=$citynames['city'];
```

Now you have to use hotel list url and concatinate **$citysearched** value instead of your destination string.

Answer (score 0):

You may using file_get_contents

below are the code

```
$request = "http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list";
$minorRev = "20";
$cid = "55505";
$api = "p9ycn9cxb2zp3k3gfvbf5aym";

//room available
$response = file_get_contents($request . '?minorRev=' . $minorRev . '&cid=' . $cid . '&apiKey=' . $api . '&locale=en_US&currencyCode=MYR&hotelId='. $hotel_id . '&arrivalDate=' . $arrivalDate . '&departureDate=' . $departureDate .  $room . '&includeDetails=true&includeRoomImages=true&options=HOTEL_DETAILS,ROOM_TYPES,ROOM_AMENITIES,HOTEL_IMAGES');
$result = json_decode($response, false);
```

By the way the api link should be http://dev.api.ean.com/

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, Finally found issue with whitespace (\n \r). You can remove whitespace using below method.

```
function prepare_xml($xml=""){
    $xml = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$xml);
    $xml = str_replace("> <","><",$xml);
    return $xml;
}
```